# template template parameter: constructor initialization

Tags: c++, class, templates, template-templates

I trying to initialize:

```
template DoubleLinkedList<Student>::DoubleLinkedList(typename Student<int> _data);
 //error: Explicit instantiation of 'DoubleLinkedList' does not refer to a function template...
```

And constructor code is:

```
template <template <class> class T> DoubleLinkedList<T>::DoubleLinkedList(T<class _T> _data){
    head = NULL;
    curr = NULL;
    len  =    0;

    push(_data);
};
```

Template class that trying to convey:

```
template <template <class> class T> class DoubleLinkedList{};
```

Template in the which trying to convey:

```
template <class _T> class Student
```

---

UP

one more question: I have a structure in class in class. How can I turn to him?
`curr = curr::_data->__name; // wrong`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You roughly want this:

```
template <template <class> class T>
class DoubleLinkedList
{
    DoubleLinkedList(T<int> _data);

    // ...
};

template <template <class> class T>
DoubleLinkedList<T>::DoubleLinkedList(T<int> _data)
{
    head = NULL;
    // ...
    push(_data);
}
```

Usage:

```
Student<int> s;
DoubleLinkedList<Student> x(s);
```

Comment: I split header.cpp, main.cpp, constructor.cpp, etc and main not see  constructor if it is not initialized (in constructor.cpp)

header:
`template <class _T> class Student{  //.. }`  

`template <template <class> class T> class DoubleLinkedList{
DoubleLinkedList(T<class _T> _data);
//...
}`

  
constructor.cpp:  

`template <template <class> class T> DoubleLinkedList<T>::DoubleLinkedList(T<class _T> _data){//...}`   


`template DoubleLinkedList<Student>::DoubleLinkedList(Student _data); //-error`